# NoReverseMatch in Django [Newbie]

Tags: python, django, url

I've been trying to figure this out for a while now but I feel like I don't know the framework well enough to debug this myself.

Basically I'm creating a little blog style site and I'm trying to create a list of posts which can link to the page to read the post itself.

I have a for loop in my template:

templates/home.py

```
<h1>Home Page</h1>
<p>welcome to the ven home page, {{ username }}!</p>

<a href="{% url 'users:logout' %}">Click here to log out</a>
<br>
<a href="{% url 'posts:create' %}">Click here to create a post</a>

<h2>Posts:</h2>

{% for post in posts %}
  <div>
    <hr>
    <a href="{% url 'posts:show' id=post.id %}"><h4>{{post.title}}</h4></a>
    <p>{{post.body}}</p>
    <p><i>{{post.tags}}</i></p>
  </div>
{% endfor%}
```

It's the line `<a href="{% url 'posts:show' id=post.id %}"><h4>{{post.title}}</h4></a>` which is causing the problem. I'm getting the error

```
Reverse for 'show' with keyword arguments '{'id': 1}' not found. 1 
pattern(s) tried: ['posts/(?P<post_id>\\d+)/view/$']
```

here is my urls file

```
url(r'^$', views.CreateFormView.as_view(), name='create'),
url(r'^(?P<post_id>\d+)/view/$', views.show_post, name='show')
```

The create method link works fine

and here is the view which loads the template:

```
def home(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('users:login')

    posts = Post.objects.all()
    username = request.user.username
    return render(request, 'ven/home.html', {'username': username, 'posts': 
    posts})
```

If more information is needed then let me know and I will provide it.
All other answers have said that this error is to do with the namespace, but it's working fine with the create link so I'm stumped.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument names are mismatching.

You'd want to change 
`<a href="{% url 'posts:show' id=post.id %}"><h4>{{post.title}}</h4></a>`

to

`<a href="{% url 'posts:show' post_id=post.id %}"><h4>{{post.title}}</h4></a>`

Since in urls.py the `show` url is defined as `'^(?P<post_id>\d+)/view/$'`.

Comment: Thanks! it seems so simple, but I just completely overlooked it